# Fragments Incompatible types

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

There `Activity` inherits `ActoinBarActivity`, it describes the sidebar (`NavigationDrawer`), by clicking on its elements open fragments. In one of the fragments have `listView`, by clicking on the item which I want to open another fragment ( staff- a list of employees - employee data). But I is an error

> Incompatible types: 
>   Required: Android.app.Fragment
>   Found:com.abc.app.EmployeeDetails

```
public class MyEmployeeFragment extends Fragment {
//some code
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    sAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),userList);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_employe, container, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(sAdapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
            Fragment f = new EmployeeDetails(); // ERROR
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, f);
            ft.commit();
            Log.i("TAG", "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = "
            + id);
        }
    });
```

`EmployeeDetails`

```
public class EmployeeDetails extends Fragment {



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employee_details, container, false);
    }


}
```

> Answer is:

All fragments must `import android.app.Fragment;` not `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc this my code

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc

How Fix it: 
HomeFragment must extend Fragment

Doesenot effect

Comment: Can you show us this class `EmployeeDetails`?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc u can see

Comment: Thanks for writing the answer clearly. May as well move to the top.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your class `EmployeeDetails` declaration, do this:

```
public class EmployeeDetails extends Fragment {
......
```

And use `import android.app.Fragment;`

not use `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Comment: Sorry, i don't saw when i posted.

Comment: Answer is:
All fragments must import  `android.app.Fragment; not android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Comment: This depend if he used the support library no?

Comment: @Garf1eld You can actually post that as an answer yourself.  Then go back to check it off when permitted.

Comment: I meant for @Garf1eld since he found the solution him/her self.  :/

Comment: Laugh. I did not realize that was @Garf1eld what he found the answer. Sorry again.

Answer (score -4):

Use `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`
Its Working me.